# How can I detect if user is typing and what he's typing using python or electron js?

Tags: javascript, python, electron, detection, pynput

I am trying to make a desktop app that will find the closest words based on the last word the user has typed. Then I want it to type the rest of the word for the user.

I have done the word recommandation in python, but I can switch to JS if needed. I'm having troble detecting if user is focused on a text input field and *actually* typing, not just pressing keys. I tryed to record each key press using pynput, then realized that's super unreliable.

I also tryed search it up, but all of the answers are for input field of HTML and JS.

My goal is to make a tool like **Sogou Pinyin**, but instead of helping to type Chinese, it auto completes English.

Does anyone have any suggestions about user typing detections? Thanks.

Comment: I think it depends on the tool you are using to build your interface. For example, if user is typing in a tkinter Entry you can use a `validatecommand` to check the word, in html and js you have `onchange` event.

Comment: I'm trying to make it to detect user typing. not just in my own app/webpage, but text fields at anywhere.